# Provision autoscale throughput on database or container in Azure Cosmos DB in NodeJS

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am able to find documentations for creating container or database with autoscaling using only .Net & Java.
Is there a way to do it for  nodeJs.

[MSDN Azure Cosmos Autoscaling Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput?tabs=api-async)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a PR to add support for that open now. This should merge fairly soon. You can track it from here. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/pull/8837